# Set path for SASnRDisplay

Tags: sasnrdisplay

Is it possible to tell `sasnrdisplay` where to find the .r-files? I have them in a seperate folder from my LaTeX-document, and I was wondering if there is a command like `\graphicspath{{"figure path"}}` for figures or `\input{"settings path"}` for settings, so I don't need to feed the `\inputRcode` command with the entire directory of the R-file.
I have tried looking in the documentation, but haven't found anything there, so it might not exist. However I hope it is just me who is blind.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution. Since `sasnrdisplay` is build using lstlisting I can simply write:

```
\lstset{inputpath = "path"}
```